# Stacked barplot R (multiple variables)

Tags: r, bar-chart

attempting to produce a stacked barplot (something like the plot below, except for multiple years and stacked bars). Ideally the x-axis would be months J, F, M...repeating (realise row names cannot duplicate but I wondered if there was a way to label the axis and then group by year) and there would be 2 y-axes - same as the example. I'm trying to plot the 2 * 'RainAvg' columns as stacked bars against the right-hand axis, and then the 2 * 'GRACEAnom' columns as 2 lines relating to the left axis. Not sure where to begin....any help appreciated as always - hopefully this is clear. I've added the first few rows of my data below the image:
[image]

```
> head(Figures, 34)
   DecimDate GRACEAnomLVB RainAvgLVB GRACEAnomVNB RainAvgVNB
1   2003.000  13.46956583   5.749109   6.15705017   3.478762
2   2003.083   6.31473051   5.331211   0.97906465   2.873399
3   2003.167   3.63883171  10.363173   0.77220028   8.090037
4   2003.250   6.49458212  17.210327   1.24673188  17.405001
5   2003.333  11.33909662  14.840302   5.56158736  15.673977
6   2003.417   9.38271799   7.536387   6.00824271   9.961779
7   2003.500   7.42633936   7.322593   6.45489806   9.617705
8   2003.583   3.60612356  11.447746   5.60098976  15.430943
9   2003.667   3.44546767   7.968092   6.63687748   8.056800
10  2003.750   2.75612873   8.769927   5.22673658   8.333266
11  2003.833   5.30475366   9.782655   6.91241363   9.305419
12  2003.917   8.68239955   7.474251   7.37673817   5.731811
13  2004.000   5.48150209   9.109684   4.04360382   5.772269
14  2004.083   2.62570392   6.976879  -0.71817402   3.780555
15  2004.167   1.45723630  10.559618  -2.23807975   6.471265
16  2004.250   5.98037042  17.895779   0.04639658  17.677118
17  2004.333   7.35279067   7.203534   3.23732162   8.284600
18  2004.417   1.41878133   4.536058   0.41008077   6.321057
19  2004.500  -0.89443672   5.439750   0.09167621   7.704055
20  2004.583  -3.98526800   9.248759  -0.22851368  12.973643
21  2004.667  -4.91880694  12.214854  -0.30143818  12.626995
22  2004.750  -4.13842871  10.903502   1.08566462  11.491835
23  2004.833   1.04833693  15.731056   4.50875694  12.300916
24  2004.917   2.93758790   8.431368   3.10471313   3.997466
```

...and so on until December 2012.

Comment: NB ggplot does not like secondary axes http://bit.ly/1Lzu7ce :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on a couple of items in the description of your chart  such as whether you're looking for one chart for all years or one for each year but the following code might help get you started.  The basic idea is to draw the bar chart and then rescale the plot window for the line plots. Chart titles and labels are added as required.

```
  org_mar <- par()$mar
  par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
  Figures <- as.matrix(Figures)
  nrow_F <- nrow(Figures)
  x_labs <- cbind(1:nrow_F,c("J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D") )[,2]
# make bar chart
  barplot(t(Figures[,c("RainAvgLVB","RainAvgVNB")]), yaxt="n", names.arg=x_labs, 
          xlab = "Monthly", font.lab=2, xlim= 1.2*c(1,nrow_F)-.5)
  axis(side=4)
  mtext("Mean Monthly Rainfall (mm)", side=4, line=2.5, font=2)
  abline(h=0)
# rescale the plot window and draw the line plots
  plot.window(xlim=c(1,nrow_F), ylim=range(Figures[,c("GRACEAnomLVB","GRACEAnomVNB")]))
  axis(side=2)
  mtext("Water Storage Anomalay (cm)", side=2, line=2.5, font=2)
  abline(v=par()$usr[1])
  lines( Figures[,2], col="black", lty=1, lwd=2)
  lines( Figures[,4], col="blue",  lty=2, lwd=2)
  par(mar=org_mar)
```

This should make a chart like the following:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. The above chart is exactly what I was after so thanks very much for the help!